# Using Python to read and edit bitmaps

Tags: image-processing, python-3.x, binary

I need to read a bitmap image file (.bmp) and split the binary data into an array of bytes, which I can then reconstitute into the original file. Eventually, I will be modifying part of each byte to store data and then reading it to get the data back.

### Details

Currently, I am using

> file = open("example.bmp","rb")
>
> data = file.read()
>
> file.close()

to get the data. However, this is rather slow and inefficient. Next I want to split it into a byte array, and change the last bit to 0 for each bit that is not part of the metadata (I will use `if` statements to subtract 1 from each odd byte). Then I will re-merge the data, and save it into a new image file with the following code:

> file = open("example2.bmp","wb")
>
> file.write(data)
>
> file.close()

although I suspect this may be sub-optimal too.

I need to know how to split a lot of binary data into bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` is already a byte array, which you can index with slice notation.  For example, according to the [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), the Bitmap File Header is in `data[0:14]`.  You may want to instead use [C libraries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439104/reading-bmp-files-in-python) to save yourself some time.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions for reading the data quickly?

Comment: That's about the fastest way to read a file, assuming it all fits into memory.  Are you sure that's the slow part of the program?

Comment: Yes - testing in isolation, it's frozen a number of times, even while reading smaller bitmaps.

Comment: The problem may be with your file system.  The files could be locked or the network may be slow.  Copy the files to your local disk first.