# Order of array columns is misaligned when trying to load a bmp image in python

Tags: python, image, bmp

I am trying to load and display a bmp image in python.
I have tried several modules now (PIL, skimage.io, matplotlib) but the image gets displayed wrongly every time.
[This is the original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXxus.png) and this is how it looks like after [loading and displaying it in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Jq9.png). (The original image gets converted to png when uploaded here).
Here is the most recent code I am using:

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
image = io.imread('107.bmp')
io.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

It looks like there is a problem with the way I am importing the bmp file. When I print the first column of the loaded image with print(image[:,0]) the resulting (494,) array already contains white 255 valued pixels that should only occur in the middle of the image somewhere around image[:, 300].
So far I could not find any options for io.imread() that help solving this problem.

What am I doing wrong? How can I load the bmp image with the correct order of columns?

The original bmp image gets displayed correctly when I open it in the default windows photos app or paint.
I am using python 3.8.5 and scikit-image 0.17.2.

Answer (score 0):

I was solve able to solve my problem by writing my own read bmp script that pays special attention to where the bmp header ends.

Following the suggested solution of [How to read bmp file header in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003833/how-to-read-bmp-file-header-in-python) I implemented the header reading and received the following information:

- Type: BM
- Size: 325142
- Reserved 1: 0
- Reserved 2: 0
- Offset: 54
- DIB Header Size: 40
- Width: 656
- Height: 494
- Colour Planes: 1
- Bits per Pixel: 8
- Compression Method: 0
- Raw Image Size: 324064
- Horizontal Resolution: 0
- Vertical Resolution: 0
- Number of Colours: 0
- Important Colours: 0

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) I understood that the BMP file header should be 54 bytes large as given by the "Offset: 54" parameter in the header. Each pixel in my grey scale image is described by 1 single byte.
However the difference between "Size: 325142" and "Raw Image Size: 324064" in the header information is 1078 bytes.

I tried a simple "read bmp" script:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
bmp = open(filename, 'rb')
bmp.seek(1078)
row = []
rows = []
for j in range(0, 494):
    for I in range(0, 656):
        row.append(int.from_bytes(bmp.read(1), 'little'))
    rows.append(row)
    row = []
data = np.array(rows, dtype = np.uint8)
data = np.flip(data, 0)
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'L')
img.show()
bmp.close()
```

When I use bmp.seek(1078) the bmp image gets read and displayed correctly just like in windows photos. When I use bmp.seek(54) the bmp image gets displayed wrongly just like when I use img = Image.open(filename) or other python libraries.
According to Wikipedia the bmp header is followed by a color table that has a length 2^n*4=1024 (n = 8: Bites per pixel value). This color table is not added to bmp files with 16 or more bites per pixel (RGB). Since 1024 + 54 = 1078 explains exactly the difference between the header length and the file length I assume that the python modules do not correctly account for the header size when reading grey scale bmp files.
Or am I missing some option in the python implementations that would solve my issue?